# How to Make a Single Subscription Box for Multiple Feeds

Tags: javascript, html, css, subscription, feed

Well I was wondering How can I make a single subscription for multiple feeds so that visitors can sign up to whatever blog they like. Well I have multiple blogs on various niche topics and I need a subscription box that gives user the option of choosing from feeds which they like by using tick options method. So for example I have three niche blogs like Web trends, Holiday Blog and Photography Blog and I want a single subscription box with a ticker option to choose what all feeds they wish to subscribe too.

Example: 
Subscribe by Email:
Choose what topic you wish to Subscribe to:

1. Web Trends
2. Holidays
3. Photography

(Tick options available for topics)

[image: Like the one in the Image but in the form of Subscription Box with Options]
Instead of managing three subscription boxes giving users a choice of subscribing to blogs they like. I am using feedburner subscription on blogs.

So is there a way of doing this instead of maintaining multiple subscription boxes. **Also can we make a feed count for the combined feed subscription to make it more viral and eye catching.** All I want is some code or if there is any site or tool which performs this then please redirect me there. A bit of CSS charm is also welcomed.:) BTW I HAVE multiple blogs on weebly and Blogger with three on weebly itself. (http://geniusknight.weebly.com) An answer will be much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are 2 questions in yours:

- How can my site offer the ability to pick the content my readers want to subscribe to?
- How can I allow my readers to pick a channel that suits them in a list of options?

The first question should probably be addressed by the subscription tool. As Feedbin does in your screenshot, when you try to subscribe, they show you that the source has multiple feeds and that you can pick one or many. Right now the boxes don't show any label. You probably have to add a `title` to the feed `<link>` tags in your HTML.

The second question can be addressed with tools like [SubToMe](https://www.subtome.com/#/). This is a univeral "follow" button. When the user clicks on it, they can pick their favorite tool to perform the subscription. Some tools are just plain RSS readers like Feedbin, some other tools use emails like Blogtrottr.

Comment: Hmm I think that image might have got you confused. You see I don't want to subscribe instead give my visitors a choice to subscribe to my various blogs which they like through all in one subscription box.

Comment: Yes, this is what I understood! My answer is exactly that!